# I duel booted ubuntu with windows and after deleting the windows partition, get errors on startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, 22.04

I duel booted ubuntu with windows and after deleting the windows partition, get errors on startup. the error are like

```
[FAILED] Failed to start process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled
[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging service
[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus system message bus
[FAILED] Failed to start D-bus system message bus
[FAILED] Failed to start user login management.
[FAILED] Failed to start system logging service
[FAILED] Failed to start thermal daemon service.
```

and this keeps going on forever. it shows the ubuntu option screen when i try to boot to ubuntu it shows the usual "lenovo ubuntu" loading screen. i am using 22.04 jammy jellyfish.
i have important files on this computer. i didn't think i needed the windows partition anymore. HOW DO I FIX THIS? more explanation:
i already HAD windows on a separate partition, and i installed ubuntu on a smaller partition. after a while, i grew accustomed to ubuntu and no longer wanted windows. so i deleted the windows partition. an hour later i had an issue where i wasn't getting internet access so i restarted. but it wouldn't boot back up. I deleted the windows partition because i wanted to extend the ubuntu partition (i wasn't sure how to yet i was just preparing) because the ubuntu partition was only 70 GB and 400gb were going unused. also btw if this is any help, it shows the ubuntu boot menu and i can attempt to boot into ubuntu it just wont. and also there is a windows boot menu option in the ubuntu boot option thing to see what to do for example, boot into ubuntu, advanced options, etc. im possibly going to try using a flashdrive with ubuntu live session and use "GRUB Repair tool". i'll give updates.

Comment: How did you "dual boot" (not "duel boot"? If you installed Ubuntu on a Windows partition... How, exactly, did you "deleting the windows partition"? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: Same happened with me just now. I went to advance option for Ubuntu and then recovery. Then check dpak and it asked me to download 450+ mb update. I only have wireless connection so I didn't do it now, but you can try that. It should work.

Comment: i split the drive and installed ubuntu on a different partition

Comment: @karel I haven't read that link yet but it doesn't seem to be on topic. i already HAD windows on a separate partition, and i installed ubuntu on a smaller partition. after a while, i grew accustomed to ubuntu and no longer wanted windows. so i deleted the windows partition. an hour later i had an issue where i wasn't getting internet access so i restarted. but it wouldn't boot back up. I deleted the windows partition because i wanted to extend the ubuntu partition (i wasn't sure how to yet i was just preparing) because the ubuntu partition was only 70 GB and 400gb were going unused.

Comment: also it still shows the ubuntu boot menu, but when i try to get into ubuntu it does the usual text showing the process of it booting but then spams the errors mentioned in the question. example: `[FAILED] Failed to start D-bus system message bus` this just repeats and it never gets into the actual os. i can get into some of the other options shown on the boot menu though. i tried to go to advanced options and then the recovery mode and none of the things shown there did anything to help.

Comment: You might want to check out your BIOS and see if SecureBoot is enabled. If so, disable it. Also, you might be missing a UEFI boot partition. Your idea of booting from a live USB is sound, it should allow you to check the partition status also.

Comment: it is not. i just checked